# Is it allowed / legal to produce a Type Rating CBT without the manufacturer's permission?

Tags: airbus, boeing, flight-simulator

Pelesys, Navcon, Flyco, CPAT Global - just to name a few companies - all provide and sell various aircraft Computer Based Training Programs.

Is it allowed / legal to program and sell products that inform and teach aircraft systems and operating procedures without permission from the aircraft manufacturer? How do they get the approval (if there is any approval required)?

Comment: Which country or regulations are you asking about?

Comment: No specific country. O

Comment: No specific country. For example company X from any european country wants to produce and sell an Airbus CBT. Are they even allowed to create a product and give instructions about the aircraft - or do they have to get approval from the manufacterer?

Comment: Sure, they can do it, but without the approval of the manufacturer they'll have a hard time getting anyone to pay for it, and if the CBT is intended to be part of a required training program, it may not get very far without the manufacturer's blessing,.